# Can't get selected item text from ListView

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, simplecursoradapter

I'm simply trying to get the text being displayed in the ListView for the row the user clicks.

**List view and adapter**

```
ListView listCurrent = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.currentlinkslist);

    try {
        SQLiteOpenHelper tractionDatabaseHelper = new TractionDatabaseHelper(this);
        db = tractionDatabaseHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        String query = "SELECT _id, QUESTION FROM QUESTION";

        cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);

        CursorAdapter listAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                cursor,
                new String[]{"QUESTION"},
                new int[]{android.R.id.text1},0);

        listCurrent.setAdapter(listAdapter);

    }catch(SQLiteException e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Database unavailable", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }


    AdapterView.OnItemClickListener itemClickListener =
            new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listCurrent,
                                        View v, int position, long id) {
                    String selectedItem = listCurrent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                    Toast.makeText(AssociateActivity.this,
                            selectedItem , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            };

    listCurrent.setOnItemClickListener(itemClickListener);
```

From everything I've seen, this code in the AdapterView.OnItemClickListener should fetch the description:

```
String selectedItem = listCurrent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
Toast.makeText(AssociateActivity.this, selectedItem, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Instead, I keep getting:

[image: toast: android.database.sqlite .SQLiteCursor@ab394dd]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Cursor cursor = (Cursor) listCurrent.getItemAtPosition.(position);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the method `getItemAtPosition()` is returning a `SQLiteCursor` object and this kind of object has no implementations of the method `toString()`. So in this case you have to return the cursor itself and parse it to your object before you call `toString()` method.

```
SQLiteCursor cursor = (SQLiteCursor) listCurrent.getItemAtPosition(position);
 String selectedItem = cursor.getString(columIndex); //columIndex is not the position

Toast.makeText(AssociateActivity.this, selectedItem, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: Thanks, this solution works perfectly with my minor edits.